# Get value of input in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I want to redirect to another page when a checkbox is clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".cbno").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('test');
        alert(this.val());
//      window.location = this.val();
    });
});
//-->
</script>

<input type="checkbox" class="cbno" name="content" value="/map/?filter=all" />
```

Pretty simple - but I cannot figure out why the second alert does not produce any output?
Internet Explorer says: "The object does not support the method val".

It works if I use this.getAttribute('value') - why does it not work with the jquery val()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
alert(jQuery(this).val());
```

Answer (score 2):

Any of `$(this).val()` or `$(this).attr("value")` or `this.getAttriute("value")` or `this.value` will work

Please be consistent on $ () and jQuery()

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cbno").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = $(this).val();
    });
});
//-->
</script>

<input type="checkbox" class="cbno" name="content" value="/map/?filter=all" />
```

Answer (score 1):

because this is not a jQuery object. you need to use $(this).val();

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
alert(this.val());
```

To:

```
alert($(this).val());
```

`$(this)` refers to checkbox you are after.

---

You can also simply use:

```
this.value
```

---

So you can modify your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".cbno").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(this.value);
        //window.location = this.value;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".cbno").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('test');
        alert( $(this).val());
//      window.location = $(this).val();
    });
});
```

this in events function is a link to the DOM element, so you should create a jQuery object with it`s methods to take them