# jQuery(selector).contains throws "no method" TypeError?

Tags: javascript, jquery

my HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="url" maxlength="10" />
</form>
```

my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var inputUrl =  $('input[name=url]');
    inputUrl.change(function() {
        alert(inputUrl);
        if ($(inputUrl).contains('watch'))
        {
            alert ('Contains watch: yes');
        }
        else
        {
            alert ('Contains watch: no');
        }
    });
});
```

Chrome Console shows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'contains'
```

What's the correct syntax for:

`if ($(inputUrl).contains('watch'))`

Comment: `inputUrl.val().indexOf('watch') != -1`...

Comment: @ZoltanToth: There is no `String.contains` in JavaScript.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053731/get-value-of-input-in-jquery and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/javascript-string-contains ... you just have to put the pieces together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (inputUrl.val().indexOf('watch') > -1) {
```

Or perhaps you only want to operate on the current one that received the event.

```
if ($(this).val().indexOf('watch') > -1) {
```

Or make it case insensitive:

```
if (/watch/i.test($(this).val())) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this . `conatins` psuedo is used to search text in the innerHtml.
it does not search in input element value

```
$(inputUrl).val().indexOf('watch') > 0
```

reference : http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 0):

My first idea was to have `input[name=url]` changed over to `input[name=url]:contains('watch')` or make inputUrl var parse so in the code, but this will only fetch text from within an element and won't have effect with regards to the value of an attr. @user1689607's answer looks like the best one in retrospect.

Comment: I don't think `:contains` considers the value of input fields. Only the text content of elements.

Comment: @FelixKling you're right, updating answer to reflect the idea and why it won't work